# hasManyToMany relation with two tables

Tags: relationship, models, phalcon

Is it possible to make many to many relation with 2 tables ?
Lets say I have following structure:

```
<?php
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;

/**
entity
-id
-name
-sub_group_id
*/
class Entity extends Model {

    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $sub_group_id;

    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->belongsTo('sub_group_id', 'SubGroup', 'id', ['alias' => 'subgroup']);
    }
}

/**
sub_group
-id
-name
-group_id
*/
class SubGroup extends Model {

    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $group_id;

    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->belongsTo('group_id', 'Group', 'id', ['alias' => 'group']);
        $this->hasMany('id', 'Entity', 'sub_group_id', ['alias' => 'entities']);
    }
}

/**
group
-id
-name
*/
class Group extends Model {

    public $id;
    public $name;

    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->hasMany('id', 'SubGroup', 'group_id', ['alias' => 'subgroups']);
    }
}
```

So Group will have 'hasMany' relation to SubGroup.
Subgroup will have 'hasMany' relation to Entity.

To get entities from group I use:

```
<?php

$entities = [];
$group = Group::findFirst();
foreach ($group->subgroups as $subgroup){
    $entities = array_merge($entities, $subgroup->entities->toArray());
}
```

What relation I should change to, lets say
Subgroup will have 'hasManyXXX' relation to Entity.

To get following result:

```
<?php

$entities = $group->subgroups->entities->toArray();
```

And is it possible at all?

Comment: Just from a quick glance you may be interested in nested sets for what you are working with. Not 100% it fits your use but just from your code it looks to be a better fit  https://github.com/phalcon/incubator/tree/master/Library/Phalcon/Mvc/Model/Behavior#selecting-from-a-tree

Comment: @david.duncan, looks good. I'll take a deep look in a future for sure - thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to do so !

```
class Group extends Model 
{
    public $id;
    public $name;

    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->hasManyToMany(
            'id',
            'SubGroup',
            'group_id',
            'id',
            'Entity',
            'sub_group_id',
            [
                'alias' => 'entities'
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Will give you an option to use:

```
$entities = $group->entities;
```

Credits to [phalcon forum](https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/8975/hasmanytomany-with-two-models#C24533)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't do that so i suggest you to add custom method in your `group` model like this:

```
class Group extends Model {

   public $id;
   public $name;

   public function initialize()
   {
       $this->hasMany('id', 'SubGroup', 'group_id', ['alias' => 'subgroups']);
   }

   public function getEntities() {
      $entities = [];
      foreach ($this->getSubgroups() as $subgroup){
         $entities = array_merge($entities, $subgroup->entities->toArray());
      }
      return $entities;
   }

}
```

Then  use this code to get your entities :

```
$group = Group::findFirst();
$entities = $group->getEntities();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an intermediate Table. An example from our application:

- @HasManyToMany(
- 'id',
- '\Core\Models\UserCarAssociation',
- 'userId', 'carId',
- '\Models\Car',
- 'id',
- [alias='car']
- )

This connects Users to Cars vie the intermediate table UserCarAssociation and informs that the foreign keys in this UserCarAssociation Table are userId and carId.

See here for some introduction to annotations, which I find much cleaner then using the initialize method to register relations: https://blog.phalconphp.com/6